# How to extract the comments part of a ppt\pptx file to a data base

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I'm building an Android app that's reads comments from an MS Power Point file.
As i get it ill have to use some API, or build a program in C#.
The problem is that i can't find a way of doing that.
I would like to hear some suggestions or to hear from programmers that accomplish
that, or something similar.

Comment: ppt and pptx are very different formats.  If you confine your work to pptx, you can simply unzip the pptx and pull xml out.  (In fact, you can rename pptx to .zip and do it in Windows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the power point api that would be the best way however I don't know if that available on android.  This is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381461.aspx) to the binary file specification for ppt files.

Comment: Thanks ill try your suggestions

Comment: I tried the zip method and it worked great, but i still be happier if someone can suggest a better way for an android app to extract "notes section" from a ppt/pptx file